# How to optimize parameters' weights?

Tags: python, optimization

I have three parameters (`a`, `b`, and `c`) and want to find the optimal combination of their weights (`w_a`, `w_b` and `w_c`) (i.e. between 1 to 10).

```
y = ((w_a * a) + (w_b * b) + (w_c * c))/(w_a + w_b + w_c)
```

the best value for weights is where we have the maximum value of y.

I already applied a sensitivity analysis (one by one) but I want to try an optimization method. Would you suggest any method?

Comment: And you expect someone to write the entire code for you? What did you try so far?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  It appears that you need to educate yourself on available optimization algorithms and their applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the parameters are and your function could reach to infinity and it does not make sense to maximise. Nevertheless, here's a way to maximise the function.

```
def func(args):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 1
    w_a, w_b, w_c = args
    out = -((w_a * a) + (w_b * b) + (w_c * c))/(w_a + w_b + w_c)
    if out > 1000 or out < -1000:
        return 0
    return out

from scipy.optimize import minimize

x0 = [0.1, 2, 3]
res = minimize(func, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
```

Note that I bounded your function within -1000, 1000. I used Nelder-Mead but you could try other optimisation algorithms too. I also returned a negative from the function because we are using a minimise routine, which is equivalent to maximising the function. `x0` is your initial guess values of weights for the function.

Running that would give you this:

```
 final_simplex: (array([[ 0.18709895,  4.98366926, -5.16577956],
       [ 0.18709896,  4.98366968, -5.16577998],
       [ 0.18709896,  4.9836698 , -5.1657801 ],
       [ 0.18709896,  4.98366971, -5.16578001]]), array([-999.99999989, -999.99999967, -999.99999919, -999.99999909]))
           fun: -999.999999885923
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 281
           nit: 144
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([ 0.18709895,  4.98366926, -5.16577956])
```

`res[x]` would give your weights `array([ 0.18709895,  4.98366926, -5.16577956])`, which maximise your function. Right now your function is maximised and has value of `res[fun] = -999.999999885923`